# Rules for constructing continous functions

Tags: general-topology

In the proof below I don't understand the statement. Because Z contains the entire image set f(X),
$f^{-1}(U) =g^{-1}$, by elementary set theory.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $x\in X$ we know that $g(x)=f(x)$, so

$$\begin{align*}
g^{-1}[B]&=\{x\in X:g(x)\in B\}\\
&=\{x\in X:g(x)\in Z\cap U\}\\
&=\{x\in X:f(x)\in Z\cap U\}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Now suppose that $f(x)\in Z\cap U$. For **every** $x\in X$ we know that $f(x)\in f[X]$, so it’s automatically true that

$$f(x)\in f[X]\cap(Z\cap U)=\big(f[X]\cap Z\big)\cap U\;,$$

and since $f[X]\subseteq Z$, we further have $f[X]\cap Z=f[X]$ and hence $f(x)\in f[X]\cap U$. Conversely, if $f(x)\in f[X]\cap U$, then certainly $f(x)\in Z\cap U$, since $f[X]\cap U\subseteq Z\cap U$. Thus,

$$\begin{align*}
\{x\in X:f(x)\in Z\cap U\}&=\{x\in X:f(x)\in f[X]\cap U\}\\
&=\{x\in X:f(x)\in U\}\\
&=f^{-1}[U]\;,
\end{align*}$$

and hence $f^{-1}[U]=g^{-1}[B]$.